# What would the query be for: Summing specific property of different Nodes of the same type

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm very new to cypher and Neo4j and I'm trying to run a specific query but I'm not sure of how to phrase it using cypher.

I'm working with a sales report dataset, and one of the type of nodes is the actual product sold. This product has 3 attributes: Name, ID, Profit. Therefore Nodes are uniquely identified through their ID, not their name. So, for example, I have Bananas that were sold in France for X Profit and Bananas that were sold in Spain for Y profit. These are two different Nodes and what separates them is their ID.

This is the cypher query used to create the graph so you can get a better grasp on it:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///SalesRecords.csv' AS row
MERGE (r:Region {Name: row.Region})
MERGE (c:Country {Name: row.Country})
MERGE (p:Product {Name: row.ItemType, ID: row.OrderID, Profit: 
row.TotalProfit})
MERGE (s:Channel {Name: row.SalesChannel})
MERGE (c)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(r)
MERGE (p)-[:SOLD_IN]->(c)
MERGE (p)-[:SOLD_THROUGH]->(s)
```

So, what I want to do is the following: I want to list all distinct products by their name and sum over their profit. So my desired end result would be a table with two columns, productName and totalProfit, where in one line of it, as an example, the productName would be Bananas and totalProfit would be X+Y.

Edit: Oh and I would like to order it by the totalProfit

If I haven't made my question clear enough please say so.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is clear. Can you show what you have tried so far and what are the issues you are facing?

Comment: yeah that's the thing, I really don't know how to tackle this. I haven't seen a similar query in any tutorial I've done. I can list the distinct products, but I'm not sure of how to associate each Node profit with each distinct product name and sum its Profit with the totalProfit for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`sum function`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/aggregating/#functions-sum) to get the sum of a set of numeric values.

Here the grouping key is `Name` property of `Product` node.

```
MATCH (p:Product)
RETURN p.Name as productName, sum(p.Profit) as totalProfit
ORDER BY totalProfit DESC
```

Comment: Oh cool it worked and the query is so simple, thank you! I have to go study a bit that grouping thing, I'm not really understanding how it does it automatically like that.

Comment: When it comes to aggregations, the non-aggregation terms become the grouping key - in this case the productName. If `Name` is a unique property of a :Product node, it would be better to aggregate with respect to `p` instead, (changing your RETURN into a WITH clause), and then `RETURN p.name, totalProfit` after that. That ensures you only perform property access on `p` after it becomes distinct from the aggregation (the grouping key of an aggregation automatically becomes distinct).